# Property anchorPoint cannot be found in forwar class object CALayer

Tags: objective-c, c, calayer, gesture-recognition

I downloaded this sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435
If I start the sample app everything is working fine.

I made my own app and copied most of the code into it. There is a method called adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer: But in this method there is a error but only in my app (see screenshot): "Property anchorPoint cannot be found in forwar class object CALayer". I am wondering how I can solve this issue, I don't know what I did wrong. It is exactly the same code from the sample. Anyone can help? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you import the **QuartzCore** framework into your project? Maybe that's why it can find the `CALayer` class

This error is thrown by XCode when it can't find a definition for `CALayer`. You should add the framework to your project and add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to wherever you are using the class

Comment: actually I didn't. So I added it, but the error still appears.

Comment: did you add the `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` too?

Comment: actually no and I just found it out myself too ;-) in the sample app it is in Prefix.pch under "Supporting files". There is the import. So I added it in my app too, and now it works, thanks!

Comment: no problem! please mark the answer as accepted if it helped so if anyone else comes across this in the future they can know for sure this solution works

Comment: I know ;-) I wanted to mark it, but it says I have to wait 4 minutes. so in a bit I will mark it ;-)